# Explicit call to a value constructor after dereferencing an iterator to std::vector<std::uniform_real_distribution<double> >

Tags: c++, random, constructor

```
  std::vector<std::uniform_real_distribution<double> > distribution_pos(10);
  for(auto it = distribution_pos.begin(); it != distribution_pos.end(); it++)
  {
     it->std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);
  }
```

I want to essentially declare a vector (size 10) of `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` objects. And then I want to loop through this vector and call the value constructor for the object (the `0.0` and `1.0` numbers should change for each pass of the loop, but I omitted that here for succinctness). The above code does not appear to do what I want. Is it possible to make an explicit call to the value constructor after already declaring `distribution_pos`?

Comment: `std::vector<std::uniform_real_distribution<double> > distribution_pos(10, std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0));` It's already constructed, or `emplace_back`.

Comment: Or simply do `*it = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);`.

Comment: As additional note: You cannot call constructors in C++ explicitly like you seem to try here. They are only implicitly called on object creation.

Comment: @user10605163 One could argue that placement-new can be used to call a constructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, what I mean is that this technically creates a new object and one cannot call a constructor on an object without creating a new object (in the same storage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not as [`std::vector`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) default constructs values and pushes them, so they cannot be constructed again.

To circumvent this, rather than creating a vector that is that size, [`reserve(10)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) (Which doesn't construct anything, just reserves memory) and then you can [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) the values, which will construct an object with the given arguments.

```
std::vector<std::uniform_real_distribution<double> > distribution_pos;
distribution_pos.reserve(10);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    distribution_pos.emplace_back(0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage of using `emplace_back()` over `push_back()` in this scenario?

Comment: And also is `distribution_pos.emplace_back(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0))` identical to `distribution_pos.emplace_back(0.0, 1.0)`?

Comment: @lamanon `push_back` has to be passed an object, which is either copied or moved into the vector (Creating a temporary object unnecesarily).

  `emplace_back(0.0, 1.0)` creates the object directly inside the vector (No copying or moving).

  `emplace_back(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0, 1.0))` will create a temporary and then call the copy or move constructor to get it into the vector.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I were to use `push_back`, I wouldn't be able to use `push_back(0.0,1.0)`? I'd have to use `push_back(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0, 1.0))`?

Comment: @lamanon You don't really need to reserve for such a small number, but it guarantees that the vector won't have to allocate memory multiple times. For example, if you instead had 100 objects, when you added the 33rd it would reallocate to be able to hold 64 objects, then when you added the 65th, it would reallocate to be able to hold 128 objects, so it wastes a lot of time. It's good practice to always reserve when you know (or have a good idea of) the final size of your vector / string.

Comment: Ah I see. I usually just use `resize()` when I for sure know the size and know that it won't change. I think `reserve()` is more suitable for vectors that change in size throughout an execution, and in that case, I'd probably just reserve an upper bound size.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to loop through this vector and call the value constructor for
>   the object

The object has already been default constructed with (0.0, 1.0) and you can't call the constructor again. You can however *assign* a new distribution by dereferencing your iterator and assigning to it:

```
    *it = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);
```

Or using a range based for loop:

```
for(auto &dist : distribution_pos) {
    dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);
}
```

If you *really* would like to keep the original distribution (perhaps to keep its internal state), you can replace its parameter object:

```
for(auto &dist : distribution_pos) {
    // get the current parameters
    auto params = dist.param();
    // create new and replace the old parameters
    dist.param(
        std::move(
            std::uniform_real_distribution<double>::param_type(
                params.a(), params.b()
            )
        )
    );
}
```